# PHP - twilio Error - 52004 Credential SID not specified

Tags: php, android, twilio, twilio-php

whenever i hit this page https://38e258f1.ngrok.io/placeCall.php it shows me 
sid value like this "**********************" but didn't make call to my app...
this is my php code for placeCall

```
<?php
/*
 * Makes a call to the specified client using the Twilio REST API.
 */
include('vendor/autoload.php');
include('config.php');

$identity = 'alice';
$callerNumber = '+923402117295';
$callerId = 'client:quick_start';
$to = isset($_GET["to"]) ? $_GET["to"] : "";
if (!isset($to) || empty($to)) {
  $to = isset($POST["to"]) ? $_POST["to"] : "";
}


$client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($API_KEY, $API_KEY_SECRET, $ACCOUNT_SID);

$call = NULL;
if (!isset($to) || empty($to)) {
  $call = $client->calls->create(
    'client:alice', // Call this number
    $callerId,      // From a valid Twilio number
    array(
      'url' => 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/incoming.php'
    )
  );
} else if (is_numeric($to)) {
  $call = $client->calls->create(
    $to,           // Call this number
    $callerNumber, // From a valid Twilio number
    array(
      'url' => 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/incoming.php'
    )
  );
} else {
  $call = $client->calls->create(
    'client:'.$to, // Call this number
    $callerId,     // From a valid Twilio number
    array(
      'url' => 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/incoming.php'
    )
  );
}
print $call->sid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Error 52004](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/52004) says that for voice calls, this means

> Credential SID can be specified in the Twilio Access Token used to register for push notifications. This error indicates that the token missed that information.

Make sure you have included the Credential SID in the Access Token when you create it for the programmable voice SDK.